# Using if and isblank to calculate a result

Tags: calculated-column

I am trying to calculate a column based on two others.  One might be blank and if it is I want the formula to use today's date.  I have tried several ways and tested it in excel to ensure I am on the right track.

Below is what I have and could really use the help to see where I have missed in the formula.

```
=IF(
    ISBLANK([Date of Follow up]),
    [TODAY]-[Date Absence Reported],
    [Date of Follow up]-[Date Absence Reported])
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right idea. You'll need to use a function for Today, I believe though. `[Today]` isn't usable in calculated columns very easily. There's some fudging around with creating a column called Today, making the calculated column, then deleting the Today column to trick SharePoint into using it. Instead, I think you want to use the function `Today()` which'll calculate what the current date is.

So if you want to go with this formula, try doing

```
=IF(
    ISBLANK([Date of Follow up]),
    Today()-[Date Absence Reported],
    [Date of Follow up]-[Date Absence Reported])
)
```

The rest of your formula looks correct to me... *However...*

Every time you update this list item, or document, when there is no `[Date to follow up]` defined, it'll recalculate the calculated column. It *will not stay static*. If this is your intention, then leave the calculation as-is. If this is not, then  make `[Date to follow up]` a required field, and have it default to `Today` in the column settings. Then you always have a date in the column, and the date won't change every time you edit the entry.

Comment: Unfortunately I need this date to be recalculated each day, however you have given me another idea.  The formula above did not work. Thanks

Comment: Can you describe how it didn’t work? What errors come up or is it formatting wrong? Also if you need it recalculated each day you’ll need to edit the item every day regardless. Calculated columns only calculate on creation or edit. You’ll either have to update the column definition somehow, or modify each list item to recalculate.

Comment: I get a message saying to has a syntax error or that the formula is not supported.  As I need this to be a calculation that automatically refreshes I am out of luck, however I will be linking to excel web services for other stats so I will utilize that functionality.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The way to achieve what you want is to build a looping workflow that will check today's date, You cannot use Today in a calculated column